# sk_buff copy & sk_buff clone

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

i m writing a module for linux kernel & it try to steal the packet & its related **sk_buff**. to do so i want to use `struct sk_buff *skb_copy(const struct sk_buff *skb, gfp_t gfp_mask)` & then pass the return type to the kernel as **packet is dropped**.

so when kernel gets the info about packet drop it try to free the sk_buff. here my question comes will it affect my newly copied skb & its pointed data of the packet? or now i can play with my new sk_buff?

or is it possible to use **skb_clone()** & use the packet data part without deleting the referenced data by old sk_buff because it will reduse copying cost of the packet.

Answer (score 5):

Using `skb_copy` will copy both the `sk_buff` and the packet to new memory. Meaning when the kernel frees the other one, the copy will not be affected.

`skb_clone` in the other hand copies the `sk_buff` structure to new memory, but not the packet. Meaning when the old one is freed, your copy will have the packet also freed.

Here are some links:

- http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/kernel/generated/networking/re68.html (skb_clone)
- http://oss.org.cn/ossdocs/gnu_linux/kernel-api/r8086.html (skb_copy)

Comment: actually i want to use the packet data with the help of skb_clone() so that no data copying will be needed only sk_buff structure will be copied. So if i decrease the reference count in the old sk_buff then is it possible ...coz during cloning i think only reference count is increased...?